# Debian Wheezy, ejabberd and forward secrecy

Tags: debian, encryption, ejabberd, jabber, xmpp

After validating of my public XMPP service on xmpp.net, I've got the error:

```
Warning: Server offers no forward-secret ciphers. Grade capped to A-.
```

Is there an easy way to enable these ciphers? As title states, I have Debian Stable and ejabberd installed from its repository.

**ADDITION**

I've checked all the servers listed in https://xmpp.net/directory.php which have `ejabberd` installed with its build date `2011/12/24`. This is Debian Wheezy's ejabberd obviously. The top score of any of these servers is `A-/A-`, so I believe it is really difficult to enable `PFS` for this software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known possibility to restrict Debian 7 Wheezy's `ejabberd 2.1.10` to use certain ciphers. The only solution is to upgrade to a more recent ejabberd version, Debian 8 Jessie's `ejabberd 14.07` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Set `ciphers` option to include only cipher suites with `DHE` in the name (Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral). For the full list of suites please have a look at https://serverfault.com/a/653656

References:

1. http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/
2. http://linux.die.net/man/1/openssl

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `Debian Wheezy`'s (stable) `ejabberd` is of version 2.1.10, which [I believe](http://docs.dvo.ru/ejabberd-2.1.10/html/guide.html) doesn't have `ciphers` setting in its config file.